# Error after updating Here-SDK from 3.2 to 3.3

Tags: android, here-api

i get exceptions / errors i cant identify after i updatet the HERE-sdk (Premium) from 3.2 to 3.3 . The Errors / Exceptions :

```
E/art:: No implementation found for void com.nokia.maps.VenueServiceImpl.createNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, int, boolean) (tried Java_com_nokia_maps_VenueServiceImpl_createNative and Java_com_nokia_maps_VenueServiceImpl_createNative__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2IIZ)
```

and

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: de.my.app, PID: 20147
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void
com.nokia.maps.VenueServiceImpl.createNative(java.lang.String,
java.lang.String, int, int, boolean) (tried    
Java_com_nokia_maps_VenueServiceImpl_createNative and 
Java_com_nokia_maps_VenueServiceImpl_createNative__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2IIZ)
at com.nokia.maps.VenueServiceImpl.createNative(Native Method)
at com.nokia.maps.VenueServiceImpl.<init>(VenueServiceImpl.java:68)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueService.<init>(VenueService.java:314)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueService.a(VenueService.java:271)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueService.getInstance(VenueService.java:301)
at com.nokia.maps.VenueMapLayerImpl.<init>(VenueMapLayerImpl.java:176)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueMapLayer.<init>(VenueMapLayer.java:92)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueMapFragment.a(VenueMapFragment.java:494)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueMapFragment.a(VenueMapFragment.java:88)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueMapFragment$3$1.b(VenueMapFragment.java:457)
at com.nokia.maps.ApplicationContext.check(Native Method)
at com.here.android.mpa.venues3d.VenueMapFragment$3.onEngineInitializationCompleted(VenueMapFragment.java:450)
at com.nokia.maps.bt.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:584)
at com.nokia.maps.bt.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:83)
at com.nokia.maps.bt$1.onEngineInitializationCompleted(MapFragmentImpl.java:130) 
at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$10.run(MapsEngine.java:2333)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

any suggestions how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to delete the jniLibs Folder...